# Stylecop issues SA1201 :Order of items in a class

Tags: c#, asp.net, stylecop

After Stylecop warning SA1201 I have modified class as follows

```
/// <summary>
/// Class Data 
/// </summary>
public class DataClass
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  Gets or sets Id
    /// </summary>
    public string Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set { this.id = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Gets or sets Name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Declare variable name
    /// </summary>
    private string name;

    /// <summary>
    /// Declare variable id
    /// </summary>
    private string id;
}
```

Still the same error is showing
"All properties must be placed after all fields"

Comment: You've got it backwards.  `id` and `name` before `Id` and `Name`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're mixing up properties and fields. Properties use getters and setters, while fields are "traditional" variables.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

You code should look like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Class Data 
/// </summary>
public class DataClass
{    
    /// <summary>
    /// Declare variable name
    /// </summary>
    private string name;

    /// <summary>
    /// Declare variable id
    /// </summary>
    private string id;

    /// <summary>
    ///  Gets or sets Id
    /// </summary>
    public string Id
    {
        get { return this.id; }
        set { this.id = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  Gets or sets Name
    /// </summary>
    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }
}
```